# nvidia-docker run vs docker run --runtime=nvidia

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

Is there a difference between:

`nvidia-docker run`

and

`docker run --runtime=nvidia` ?

In the [official docs](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) they use the latter but I've seen the former in other tutorials online.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`docker run --runtime=nvidia` is only available since nvidia-docker v2.

Both commands are equivalent with nvidia-docker v2, the former is a script provided for [backward compatibility](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Advanced-topics#backward-compatibility) with nvidia-docker v1.